# How do you input a string then assign a number to it

Tags: python, string, function, variables, input

Hello i'm doing some personal python learning and i have a practice problem i'm trying to figure out. The main goal is to play paper rock scissors with the computer. Your supposed to input "paper" "rock" or "Scissors" as a user answer and the computer will randomly generate a number from 1-3 that corresponds to a particular choice. I can get the program to work fine if the user inputs a number from 1-3 but that's not what the question asks. I feel like i've tried everything like assigning each name to the corresponding number, creating an if then statement that then reassigns the choice to the numerical value but it always just gets stuck after the input prompt and doesn't move forward with the code. I know the issue lies most likely in the line 6 because thats the last spot it executes.. not sure how to fix it. Also if anyone can give me some pointers on how this could look a little cleaner or if this is roughly what is should look like in terms of efficiency and cleanliness. Keep in mind i have not learned anything too advanced like dictionaries lists ect. Problem should be solved using basic stuff for now. Thank you!

```
import random

def main():
    global user_answer
    print('lets play paper rock scissors')
    number = comp_answer()
    user_answer = int(input('What do you choose?')) <--- # i know the change would be 
    while number = comp_answer():                        # here.... maybe str(input(' ')) 
        tie(number)                                      # then define the choices? tried 
    paper_rock_scissors(number)                          # that and failed not sure if i'm 
                                                         # doing it wrong.

def comp_answer():
    number = random.randint(1,4)
    return number

def tie(number):
    print("its a tie!")
    print ("tie breaker")
    user_answer = input('What do you choose?')

def paper_rock_scissors(number):

    if number == 3 and user_answer == 1:
        print("computer: scissors")
        print("you: ",user_answer )
        print("you won!")
        print("rocks smashes scissors")

    elif number == 3 and user_answer == 2:
        print("computer: scissors")
        print("you: ",user_answer )
        print("Game over")
        print("scissors cuts paper")

    elif number == 1 and user_answer == 3:
        print("computer: rock")
        print("you: ",user_answer )
        print("Game over")
        print("rocks smashes scissors")
    elif number == 2 and user_answer == 3:
        print("computer: paper")
        print("you: ",user_answer )
        print("you won!")
        print("scissors cuts paper")

    elif number == 1 and user_answer == 2:
        print("computer: rock")
        print("you: ",user_answer )
        print("you won!")
        print("paper covers rock")
    elif user_answer == 1 and number == 2:
        print("computer: paper")
        print("you: ",user_answer )
        print("Game over")
        print("paper covers rock")
main()
```

Comment: It will be `while number == comp_answer():`

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop condition you don't compare the user's choice to the program's.

```py
def main():
    global user_answer
    print('lets play paper rock scissors')
    number = comp_answer()
    user_answer = int(input('What do you choose?'))
    while user_answer == number:
        tie(number)
        number = comp_answer()
    paper_rock_scissors(number)
```

Fix this by comparing `user_answer` and `number` instead. You also need to specify that `user_answer` is global in `tie`. The fact that `comp_answer` is recomputed in the while condition will make it so that `number` has the incorrect value when passed to `rock_paper_scissors`. Those Three changes should fix the issue.

 
As for cleanliness, global variables are generally bad practice. You could change this by changing `tie(number)` to `user_answer = tie(number)` and adding `user_answer` as an argument to `rock_paper_scissors`. The `tie` function also doesn't use it's argument so it could easily be removed.

Comment: In regards to understanding global variables is there a reason why when i tried to makes this a global variable and put it at the very top near import random why it was still considered undefined when called upon by other functions? in other words when would you use global variable_name  and put variable_name at the very top.

Comment: Also, although helpful in my typos and common practice. it doesnt solve the overall question of allowing the user to input a string of "rock","paper", or "scissors". The problem is not meant for the user to input a number i just left it that way because it was the only way i could make it "work".

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your program lies in

```
"while number = comp_answer():"
```

It should be a "==" for comparison. "=" is used for assignment and what we need here is an equal to evaluation. 
Also,

```
while number == comp_answer():
```

doesn't really equate to a tie. It just checks whether the stored value number is equal to the output from comp_answer(). You might wanna equate "user_input" with "number" to check for the same. 
P.S. the comp_answer() should be called again in tie function

Try this:
I've put the print statements to a new function that makes the program a big easier to read and shorter.

```
import random

def main():
    global user_answer
    print('lets play paper rock scissors')
    number = comp_answer()
    user_answer = int(input('What do you choose?'))  
    while number == user_answer:                        
        tie()                                       
    paper_rock_scissors(number)                          

def comp_answer():
    number = random.randint(1,4)
    return number

def tie():
    global number
    print("its a tie!")
    print ("tie breaker")
    number = comp_answer()
    user_answer = input('What do you choose?')

def print_ans(computer, user, explanation, win):
    print("computer: ", computer)
    print("you: ", user)
    print(explanation)
    if win:
        print("you won!")
    else:
        print("Game over")

def paper_rock_scissors(number):
    if number == 3:
        if user_answer == 1:
            print_ans("scissors", "rock", "rocks smashes scissors", win=True)
        else:
            print_ans("scissors", "paper", "scissors cut paper", win=False)
    elif number == 1:
        if user_answer == 3:
            print_ans("rock", "scissors", "rocks smashes scissors", win=False)
        else:
            print_ans("rock", "paper", "paper covers rock", win=True)
    else:
        if user_answer == 1:
            print_ans("paper", "rock", "paper covers rock", win=False)
        else:
            print_ans("paper", "scissors", "scissors cut paper", win=True)


main()
```

If you want the user to input string instead of integers, the code will look somewhat like this (mind you I will be using [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) as it makes things easier and I think it is important for everyone to know about them, so read up a bit on them):

```
import random

num_mappings = {"rock":1 , "paper":2 , "scissors":3}

def main():
    global user_answer
    print('lets play paper rock scissors')
    number = comp_answer()
    user = input('What do you choose?') 
    user_answer = num_mappings[user] 
    while number == user_answer:                        
        tie()                                       
    paper_rock_scissors(number)                          

def comp_answer():
    number = random.randint(1,4)
    return number

def tie():
    global number
    print("its a tie!")
    print ("tie breaker")
    number = comp_answer()
    user = input('What do you choose?') 
    user_answer = num_mappings[user]

def print_ans(computer, user, explanation, win):
    print("computer: ", computer)
    print("you: ", user)
    print(explanation)
    if win:
        print("you won!")
    else:
        print("Game over")

def paper_rock_scissors(number):
    if number == 3:
        if user_answer == 1:
            print_ans("scissors", "rock", "rocks smashes scissors", win=True)
        else:
            print_ans("scissors", "paper", "scissors cut paper", win=False)
    elif number == 1:
        if user_answer == 3:
            print_ans("rock", "scissors", "rocks smashes scissors", win=False)
        else:
            print_ans("rock", "paper", "paper covers rock", win=True)
    else:
        if user_answer == 1:
            print_ans("paper", "rock", "paper covers rock", win=False)
        else:
            print_ans("paper", "scissors", "scissors cut paper", win=True)


main()
```

However, keep in mind, your code will fail if the user types anything other than "rock", "paper" or "scissors". I suggest you look into [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) to get a good grasp and improve on those aspects.

Comment: Hey @Arpit thank you for helping. I had a question however in you def print_ans  function where you have the parameters  computer, user, explanation, win then you print the string for each one with the argument you want to be printed however i'm not sure how you are able to do this given that you never defined any of these. would you mind explaining how you were able to do this?

Comment: Also, this doesn't allow the input to be a string. The user should be able to input "rock", "paper" or "scissors" not a number.

Comment: Hi, @Carina I'm glad you found this helpful. I couldn't understand your first question. I'll edit the code a bit if you want the user to inputs strings.

Comment: Hi @Arpit  thank you for showing another solution. in regards to my first question ill try to explain myself clearer.  In your attached above code you created a function called *def print_ans(computer, user, explanation, win): *  then printed each argument for the given parameters. im confused on how you were able to execute this when you never defined what computer, user, explanation and win were.. so how are you able to execute this for example: print(explanation) or print("you: ", user)

Comment: Ohh. All the parameters are defined and passed on when the function is called later. For example, the statement: *print_ans("paper", "scissors", "scissors cut paper", win=True)* supplies the arguments and calls the print_ans function.